# Change direction of layout to RTL in Ant Design Blazor

Tags: blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor, ant-blazor

How can I change direction of layout to RTL in Ant Blazor? There is not documentation about this. I mean changing direction to RTL similar the way Ant Blazor website changes direction by a button in header and using ConfigProvider.

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time, I found that Router tag in App.razor should be wrapped inside ConfigProvider tag.

```
<ConfigProvider>
   <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
   </Router>
</ConfigProvider>
<AntContainer />
```

After that you could use ConfigProvider as a CascadingParameter in your razor files.

```
[CascadingParameter] public ConfigProvider ConfigProvider { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the html tag to this:

```
 <html dir="rtl" data-direction="rtl">
```

and it will change the direction to rtl

Comment: It's not change the controls direction

Comment: some controls direction are not wel defined in the css this trick only applies the rtl as it is implemented and used in ant blazor document , so to have more accurate you can download the ant design original css files